# How to use rxjava2 with retrofit in android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

Hi I am trying to learn rxjava2. I am trying to call API's using rxjava2 and using retrofit for building URL and converting JSON into Moshi.

I want to use `Observable` pattern with `retrofit`. Does anyone know whats way to do it ? Any standard and best approach like wrapper for error handling and all ?

**AppModule.kt**

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofit(moshi: Moshi, okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
}
```

**ApiHelperImpl.kt**

```
@Inject
lateinit var retrofit: Retrofit

override fun doServerLoginApiCall(email: String, password: String): Observable<LoginResponse> {
    retrofit.create(RestApi::class.java).login(email, password)
}
```

I am calling `doServerLoginApiCall` from the `LoginViewModel` like below

**LoginViewModel.kt**

```
fun login(view: View) {
    if (isEmailAndPasswordValid(email, password)) {
        ApiHelperImpl().doServerLoginApiCall(email, password)
    }
}
```

**RestApi.kt**

```
interface RestApi {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/partner_login")
    fun login(@Field("email") email: String, @Field("password") password: String): Call<LoginResponse>
}
```

**LoginResponse.kt**

```
data class LoginResponse(

        @Json(name = "code")
        val code: Int? = null,

        @Json(name = "otp_verify")
        val otpVerify: Int? = null,

        @Json(name = "data")
        val userDetails: UserDetails? = null,

        @Json(name = "message")
        val message: String? = null,

        @Json(name = "status")
        val status: String? = null
)
```

Comment: take a look at this project: https://github.com/Fakher-Hakim/Rx-Android-Samples

Comment: What is your exactly problem?

Comment: @Watcharin.s I am new and bit confused way to use rxjava2 in my case and how to send back result to view model

Comment: you can check my repo: https://github.com/savepopulation/wikilight

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the rough idea to show you how to use Retrofit2 with RxJava2. you can find a lot of tutorial in google.

Step 1: 
Add the following dependencies to your gradle file

```
// Rx stuff
compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxAndroidVersion"

// retrofit
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitVersion"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofitVersion"
```

Step 2: Create you Retrofit API interface like you do but it has a bit difference that is the return type should be `Observable<LoginResponse>` not a `Call<LoginResponse>`

```
interface RestApi {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/partner_login")
    fun login(@Field("email") email: String, @Field("password") password: String): Observable<LoginResponse>
}
```

Step 3: 
build you retrofit API object:

```
retrofit.create(RestApi::class.java).login(email, password)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe{ loginResponse ->
             // TODO deal with your response here
 }
```

Comment: Any standard and best approach like wrapper for error handling and all ?

Comment: see this https://rongi.github.io/kotlin-blog/rxjava/rx/2017/08/01/error-handling-in-rxjava.html?utm_source=Android+Weekly&utm_campaign=51f4814861-android-weekly-269&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-51f4814861-337969913

Comment: can you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119352/rxjava2-how-to-pass-baseview-to-the-callbackwrapper

Answer (score 1):

Do not you just know how to return results?

The way to return results with rx is as follows.

```
ApiHelperImpl().doServerLoginApiCall(email, password)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe { result ->
                    // doSomething
                }
```

`subscribeOn` calls api in a other thread.
`observeOn` is a process for processing `subscribe` in the main thread.
`subscribe` has multiple overloading methods. Please check the [document](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following article: [link]:https://medium.com/3xplore/handling-api-calls-using-retrofit-2-and-rxjava-2-1871c891b6ae